# Problem while iterating a vector using range-based loop

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

I am doing a basic implementation of RANSAC using PCL lib. Although, the question here is related to C++ concepts only.

I am iterating a point cloud in two ways; one works perfectly, and the other iterates less than half of the points. I just want to understand the reason why one of the two is not working.

Working one:

```
    for (int index=0; index < cloud->points.size(); index++)
    {
        float distance = abs(A * cloud->points[index].x + B * cloud->points[index].y + C * cloud->points[index].z + D) / sqrt(A * A + B * B + C * C);

        // Check for the two points set above, if present ignore
        if (set_inliers.count(index) > 0)
            continue;

        // If distance is smaller than threshold count it as inlier
        if (distance <= distanceTol)
            set_inliers.insert(index);

        std::cout << "Point Number: " << index << std::endl;
    }
```

The loop which doesn't work:

```
int index = 0;

for (auto elem : cloud->points)
{
    float distance = abs(A * elem.x + B * elem.y + C * elem.z + D) / sqrt(A * A + B * B + C * C);

    // Check for the two points set above, if present ignore
    if (set_inliers.count(index) > 0)
        continue;

    // If distance is smaller than threshold count it as inlier
    if (distance <= distanceTol)
        set_inliers.insert(index);

    std::cout << "Point Number: " << index << std::endl;
    index++;
}
```

cloud->points is a vector ( see below ). Thus, the range-based loop introduced in C++11 should work and both loops mentioned above should be identical, right? I guess I have missed something here.

Variable Details:

In the above code, the var cloud is declared as:

```
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud
```

Ptr is a vector of following:

```
 std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ>
```

cloud->points is defined as:

```
 std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> > pcl::PointCloud< PointT >::points
```

For reference: [PCL Point Cloud Reference](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.1/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#af16a62638198313b9c093127c492c884)

I have some understanding issue here and thus it will be great if someone can help out!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both loops should do the same thing.  One difference is `auto elem : cloud->points` is going to make a copy of each element in the vector, so you could change it to `auto& elem : cloud->points` or `const auto& elem : cloud->points` to stop that.  If that doesn't make a difference we really need a [mre].

Comment: What does it mean: "The loop which doesnt work"?
Why it doesn't work? You got any errors? Or what?

Comment: You also need to increment `index` before `continue;`, not just at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a complete example of your code it is hard to say, but there is one thing that is different in the two loops. Everything else removed we have

```
for (int index=0; index < cloud->points.size(); index++) { 
    if (some_condition) continue;
    // use index
}
```

vs

```
int index = 0;
for (auto elem : cloud->points) {
    if (some_contition) continue;
    // use index
    index++;
}
```

In the range-based for-loop the index is not incremented when `some_condition == true`. In the index based loop, `index` is incremented on each iteration. I suppose the two loop actually do have same number of iterations, but `index` will have a different value after the range-based loop.

Fancy facilities for range-based loops are still rather scarce. If you do not want to resort to boost or other third-party libraries I would suggest to use index based loops when you need the index. Range-based loops are good when you do not care about the index.

Comment: @blackbug that was not my intention. Try to see it positive, learning is done by making mistakes. You should feel like you know more than before, that would great ;)

Answer (score 1):

The second loop has a `continue`, an opportunity to skip `index++`.  If that ever happens, points at the end can never be referenced by an index value.

It looks like you want `index` to increment with every loop iteration, unconditionally.  The simplest change would be to replace `continue` with

```
{
    index++;
    continue;
}
```